# stop and play music for incoming call

Tags: android

I nedd to stop music for incoming call and then play after call end and thes is my code i use but donot work  the music not stop i dont know what wrong in this code ??
i want to stop music when call is coming and only ring tone  i want to listen but now music and ring tone play in the same time

```
package com.test.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;


public class StreamService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "StreamService";
    MediaPlayer mp;
    boolean isPlaying;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Notification n;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;


    // Change this int to some number specifically for this app
    int notifId = 5315;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        // Init the SharedPreferences and Editor
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        editor = prefs.edit();

        // Set up the buffering notification
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        String notifTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        String notifMessage = context.getResources().getString(R.string.buffering);

        n = new Notification();
        n.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        n.tickerText = "Buffering";
        n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent, 0);

        n.setLatestEventInfo(context, notifTitle, notifMessage, pIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(notifId, n);

        // It's very important that you put the IP/URL of your ShoutCast stream here
        // Otherwise you'll get Webcom Radio
        String url = "http://3.187.5.93:9230/";
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(url);
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "IllegalStateException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException");
        }   
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        mp.start();
        // Set the isPlaying preference to true
        editor.putBoolean("isPlaying", true);
        editor.commit();

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String notifTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        String notifMessage = context.getResources().getString(R.string.now_playing);

        n.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        n.tickerText = notifMessage;
        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent, 0);

        n.setLatestEventInfo(context, notifTitle, notifMessage, pIntent);
        // Change 5315 to some nother number
        notificationManager.notify(notifId, n);
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
        editor.putBoolean("isPlaying", false);
        editor.commit();
        notificationManager.cancel(notifId);
    }

    private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

        // needed for logging
        String TAG = "PhoneCallListener";

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
                // phone ringing
                Log.i(TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
                // active
                Log.i(TAG, "OFFHOOK");

                isPhoneCalling = true;
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
                // run when class initial and phone call ended,
                // need detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
                Log.i(TAG, "IDLE");

                if (isPhoneCalling) {

                    Log.i(TAG, "restart app");

                    // restart call application
                    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                    getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);

                    isPhoneCalling = false;
                }

            }


    }
    }

}
```

Comment: So, you want to play music, and when a call comes in, pause the music, and when the call ends, start it back up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener =
              new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
                      public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                        switch (focusChange) {

                               case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) :
                               // Lower the volume while ducking.
                               mp.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
                               break;
                               case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) :
                               mp.pause();
                               break;

                               case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) :
                               mp.stop();

                               break;

                               case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) :
                               // Return the volume to normal and resume if paused.
                               mp.setVolume(1f, 1f);
                               mp.start();
                               break;
                               default: break;
    }
    }
    };




    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

            // Request audio focus for playback
            int result = am.requestAudioFocus(focusChangeListener,
            // Use the music stream.
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            // Request permanent focus.
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);


            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            // other app had stopped playing song now , so u can do u stuff now .

            }
                }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.